# How to resolve json strings must not have leading spaces in terraform for AWS ecr IAM role

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-ecr

I saw a lot of topic opened for this kind of issue, but impossible to resolve this.

I'm trying to create AWS IAM role with attachments policy but I have always this issue :

> Error: Error creating IAM Role test-role: MalformedPolicyDocument: JSON strings must not have leading spaces

I am fully aligned with the documentation :

**Role : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role**

**Policy attachment: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role_policy_attachment**

Please find my configuration

```
resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "test-role-profile" {
  name = "test-role-profile"
  role = aws_iam_role.test-role.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "test-role" {
  name               = "test-role"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Principal": {
          "Service": "ecr.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Sid": ""
      }
    ]
  }
  EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "test-role-policy" {
  name        = "test-role-policy"
  description = "Test role policy"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
          "ecr:CreateRepository",
          "ecr:DescribeImages",
          "ecr:DescribeRegistry",
          "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
          "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
          "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicy",
          "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicyPreview",
          "ecr:GetRegistryPolicy",
          "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
          "ecr:ListImages",
          "ecr:ListTagsForResource",
          "ecr:PutLifecyclePolicy",
          "ecr:PutRegistryPolicy",
          "ecr:SetRepositoryPolicy",
          "ecr:StartLifecyclePolicyPreview",
          "ecr:PutImage"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "test-role-attach" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.test-role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.test-role-policy.arn
}
```

Version : Terraform v0.12.31

Anyone have an idea ?

Thks

Answer (score 7):

You have some space before the first `{` character in the JSON string here:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "test-role" {
  name               = "test-role"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
  {
```

It should look like this instead:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "test-role" {
  name               = "test-role"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
```

I personally recommend either switching to the `jsonencode()` method of building JSON strings, which you can see examples of [in your first link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role), or using [aws_iam_policy_document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document) to construct your IAM policies.